# How to define a function and loop it

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I want to loop my code that way if someone inputs something invalid (such as a letter), it returns again to the initial code asking for user weight in kg

```
def weightOnPlanet():
    #Determine your weight in kg
    pounds = int(input("Enter weight in Pounds: "))
    kgs = pounds/2.2046

    print("The weight in kgs is",round(kgs))

    #Input convert weight (lbs -> kgs)
    Weight = float(input("Enter your weight on Earth in kg: "))

    if Weight <= 0:
        print("Your weight must be positive.") 
    else:
        print("Weight on Mercury is", Weight*0.38, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Venus is", Weight*0.91, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Mars is", Weight*0.38, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Jupiter is", Weight*2.34, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Saturn is", Weight*1.06, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Uranus is", Weight*0.92, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Neptune is", Weight*1.19, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Pluto is", Weight*0.06, "kg.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    weightOnPlanet()
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: what would constitute an invalid input?

Comment: You do it like any other loop.  You start with `while True:`, then when they answer the questions successfully, you do a `break`.  If you don't break, it cycles around and asks again.

Comment: Unrelated: `Weight` variable is not needed. You should be checking `pounds <= 0` first. Then multiply `kgs`, which will always be positive...

Answer (score -1):

Hey it is very simple use this syntax:

```py
def function_name(arg1, arg2):
    your code block
```

What this syntax does is simply giving a name to a code block that you can use to execute that block. Now every time you execute the function you execute the code block inside. For your case it will look like this

```py
def main():
    #Determine your weight in kg
    pounds = int(input("Enter weight in Pounds: "))
    kgs = pounds/2.2046

    print("The weight in kgs is",round(kgs))

    #Input convert weight (lbs -> kgs)
    Weight = float(input("Enter your weight on Earth in kg: "))

    if Weight <= 0:
        print("Your weight must be positive.")
    else:
        print("Weight on Mercury is", Weight*0.38, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Venus is", Weight*0.91, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Mars is", Weight*0.38, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Jupiter is", Weight*2.34, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Saturn is", Weight*1.06, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Uranus is", Weight*0.92, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Neptune is", Weight*1.19, "kg.")
        print("Weight on Pluto is", Weight*0.06, "kg.")
```

Now every time you call main you execute your code block.
For example you may execute 3 times like this

```py
main()
main()
main()
```

or like this:

```py
for i in range(3):
    main()
```

or even you can execute for ever like this:

```py
while True:
    main()
```